# Xbox 360 controller commands to Uno-compatible board via USB module

Tags: usb, m5stack

I am trying to receive commands on a third-party **Arduino-Uno-compatible board** from an **Xbox 360 controller** via an **M5Stack USB module** but I am not seeing the behavior I expect (see heading Expected Behavior).

To be clear, I am talking about reading commands from an Xbox controller using an Arduino, *not* emulating an Xbox controller using an Arduino.

## Hardware

[image]

- A Bluno Nano. (An Arduino-Uno-compatible board in a Nano-like form factor with program uploading and serial communication via a matching Bluetooth USB dongle. However, I am using a wired USB connection to my PC instead.) The board is recognized as an Uno by the Arduino IDE. The same board has worked as expected for other projects.
- An [M5Stack USB module](https://docs.M5Stack.com/en/module/usb) (with a MAX3421E chip), which is  primarily meant to be compatible with an M5Stack microcontroller module. Either way, the USB module communicates using SPI.
- A *wireless* Xbox 360 controller, but I connected it to the USB module using a USB cable that [plugs in to the controller](https://static.bhphoto.com/images/images500x500/1414082712_1071751.jpg) with a seemingly proprietary connector. Should be in working order.

I am not using an [Xbox 360 wireless receiver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l1Ys.jpg) to connect to the Xbox controller, nor do I want to connect to it wirelessly.

### Wiring

- I connected the GND (#1/3/5), +5V (#28, VBUS), SCLK (#11, GPIO18), MISO (#9, GPIO19) and MOSI (#7, GPIO23) pins of the USB module to the corresponding pins of the Bluno Nano: GND, +5V, SCK (D13), MISO (D12), and MOSI (D11).
- I tried pulling the USB module's EN pin (#6) up to +5V in attempt to make sure it's enabled.
- I tried pulling the SS pin up/down. I have not tried connecting it to pins D10 or D8, both of which I have seen as SS pins on Arduino Nano pinout diagrams.
- I have not tried connecting the INT pin (#2, GPIO35) to anything.
- I believe these are the only useful pins on the USB module.

#### USB module schematic

The useful pinout is in the bottom right corner.

[image]

### Attempts

- Unplugging and re-plugging the Bluno Nano's USB cable with my PC.
- Pressing the Bluno Nano's reset button.
- Unplugging and re-plugging the Xbox controller's USB cable with the USB module, or vice versa (that is, starting with it unplugged).
- Pressing or holding the center "X" button or other buttons on the controller, presumably to turn it on or hopefully enter some kind of connection-setup mode, maybe.
- Using a wired USB mouse instead of the Xbox controller.
- Trying various combinations of the above in different orders.

I have ensured that the USB module is receiving power (even though it seems to have no power indicator LED) by using it's additional 5V and GND pins to successfully drive a digital input pin on the Bluno Nano high or low.

I have ensured that the Xbox controller is receiving power because the center "X" button lights up upon being pressed.

## Software

- Windows 11
- Arduino IDE 2.0
- [USB_Host_Shield_2.0](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0) version 1.6.2 (latest) installed through the library manager. Note that this library seems to be primarily designed for a particular USB host shield, but I see it being used with other USB host shields, including in my USB module's documentation. There is a [library for Xbox 360](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0#xbox-360-library) therein which works with a USB controller or a wireless controller, with example sketches for each.

Either example sketch uploads successfully without errors (although the programmer sometimes gets stuck not responding, whereupon I disconnect, let it error out, reconnect, and retry uploading).

In the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor, I set the baud rate to 115200 to match that specified in either example sketch.

### Expected behavior

To be printed in the Serial Monitor (`<...>` is how I indicate my comments):

```
XBOX USB Library Started  <instead of "OSC did not start" followed by unresponsiveness to controller button presses, etc.>
<Xbox controller commands upon controls/buttons being pressed, e.g., "LeftHatX: ...">
```

### Attempts

- The USB Host Shield 2.0 documentation says about use with an Xbox 360 controller: "To use it via USB use the XBOXUSB library or to use it wirelessly use the XBOXRECV library. Note that a Wireless controller can NOT be used via USB!". It is unclear to me if my wired USB connection to my wireless controller calls for the XBOXUSB or XBOXRECV library, so I tried both libraries (tried both accompanying example sketches) to no avail.
- I tried removing the following code snippets one-by-one and in some combinations, to no avail. The program uploads successfully in every case.

  ```
  #include <SPI.h>
  ```

  ```
  #if !defined(__MIPSEL__)
    while (!Serial); // Wait for serial port to connect - used on Leonardo, Teensy and other boards with built-in USB CDC serial connection
  #endif
  ```

  ```
  XBOXUSB Xbox(&Usb);
  <...along with the code in `loop()` that requires it to be defined.>
  ```

  ```
  if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
    Serial.print(F("\r\nOSC did not start"));
    while (1); //halt
  }
  Serial.print(F("\r\nXBOX USB Library Started"));
  ```

  **The program failed here because `Usb.Init() == -1`.**
- I tried changing

  ```
  if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
    Serial.print(F("\r\nOSC did not start"));
    while (1); //halt
  }
  Serial.print(F("\r\nXBOX USB Library Started"));
  ```

  to

  ```
  while (Usb.Init() == -1);
  Serial.print(F("\r\nXBOX USB Library Started"));
  ```

  in attempt to keep trying to enable the connection (while I pressed the controller's "X" and other buttons) to no avail.
- I also tried changing the same snippet to

  ```
  Usb.Init()
  ```

  in attempt to ignore the `-1` return value (which I presume represents an error) and proceed anyway, to no avail.
- Using an older version of the USB Host Shield 2.0 library.
- Setting the following in the library's `settings.h`, with no apparent change in output.

  ```
  /* Set this to 1 to activate serial debugging */
  #define ENABLE_UHS_DEBUGGING 1
  ```
- Setting the following in `XBOXUSB.cpp` and `XBOXRECV.cpp`, with no apparent change in output.

  ```
  #define EXTRADEBUG // Uncomment to get even more debugging data
  #define PRINTREPORT // Uncomment to print the report send by the Xbox 360 Controller
  ```

For trying with a wired USB mouse instead of the Xbox controller, I used `USB_Host_Shield_2.0/examples/HID/USBHIDBootMouse/USBHIDBootMouse.ino`, attempted additionally with some of the above modifications, to no avail in any case, leading me to believe that the problem is not specific to the Xbox controller or library for it.

I have also tried the [example sketch](https://github.com/m5stack/M5Stack/blob/master/examples/Modules/USB_MAX3421E/usb_mouse/usb_mouse.ino) from the M5Stack USB module documentation after removing parts that would be specific to an M5Stack microcontroller module and unecessary for testing purposes. This was no different.

---

I am completely lost on what else to try hardware- and software-wise. I have tried searching many questions. I suspect that I'm missing something simple and obvious, or that my setup can't work for whatever reason.

Thank you

---

## Update

After getting past the `Usb.Init()` problem by connecting the USB module's SS pin, the connection with the Xbox controller still wasn't being established and commands were not being received.

Comment: UPDATE: I've gotten past `Usb.Init()` successfully by connecting the SS pin to D10 (either with XBOXUSB or XBOXRECV) but the main code in `loop()` that is now reached is not working either because `Xbox.Xbox360Connected == 0`. This is the case even if I check `Xbox.Xbox360Connected` after a delay or after pressing buttons on the Xbox controller.

Comment: UPDATE: I've gotten exactly the same thing working but with the wired USB mouse and `USB_Host_Shield_2.0/examples/HID/USBHIDBootMouse/USBHIDBootMouse.ino`.

Comment: *I tried pulling the SS pin up/down* - I was about to suggest that the SS pin is usually controlled by software, and that asserting it usually signals the start of a "transaction" - however the protocol defines that.

Comment: You are certain that the controller *also* sends its data via the USB and not just wireless?

Comment: @NickGammon I think you're right about the SS pin. Regarding whether the USB is for data and not solely for power, I can't be 100% sure, but I suspect that it is for data because the USB cable's proprietary connector with the Xbox 360 controller has a sort of 'cuff' around it that seems to very intentionally block the "Connect" button on the back of the controller from being pressed; the USB cable appears to preclude a wireless connection by design. How do I test it -- try to play using the controller in a Faraday cage? :D

Comment: Well, if you had a USB analyser (which aren't cheap) you could see if the data being sent changes as you press buttons.

Comment: @NickGammon Thanks! I might consider trying a different controller and/or cable, buying an Xbox 360 wireless receiver, or using a joystick instead of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that, upon plugging the USB cable into my PC rather than the USB module, the controller appears as "Xbox 360 Wireless Controller via Play & Charge Kit" under "Xbox 360 Peripherals" in the Device Manager.

Turns out, "Play & Charge Kit" refers to the controller's removable rechargeable battery and the USB cable.

According to [this](https://linustechtips.com/topic/658562-solved-xbox-360-controller-via-play-and-charge-kit/), "The play and charge kit only carries power. It does not carry the data required to connect a controller to a PC."